# Install4J: desktop icon is not created during installation

Tags: install4j

Install4J does not create desktop shortcut, even for sample apps (Hello world). All icon files are included. exe file properties show that shortcut file is found, but shortcut is not created. Did anyone encounter this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I see no such problem here with 7.0.8.

Most likely you have added the "Add a desktop link" action before the "Install files" action has run. In that case the link is not created because the target file is not found.

Answer (score 0):

Desktop shortcut appears on my computer (Win 10) only after desktop refresh. After installation with install4j try right click on desktop and select Refresh in popup menu.